# Why do I need to provide enclosing class object but not enclosed class object

Tags: java, inheritance, inner-classes

```
class OuterA {
    class InnerA {
    }
}
class SubclassC extends OuterA.InnerA { 
    SubclassC(OuterA outerRef) {
        outerRef.super(); 
    }
}
class XYZ {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new SubclassC(new OuterA());
    }
}
```

In the above code

1. Why do I need to pass `OuterA` object reference to `SubclassC` constructor for the .java file to compile?
2. Why is `InnerA` object reference not required to be passed to `SubclassC` constructor?

Comment: Note that if your class `InnerA` does not need to be bound to an instance of `OuterA`, you can declare it `static` and this "problem" will go away. From your comments it sounds like that might be helpful.

Answer (score 6):

> Why do I need to pass OuterA object reference to SubclassC constructor for the .java file to compile?

Because `SubclassC` *extends* the definition of the `InnerA` class. Meanwhile, `InnerA` class is **bound** to `OuterA` (i.e. all the instances of `InnerA` will be bound to a corresponding instance of `OuterA`). Therefore, to obtain an instance of `SubclassC`, you need an instance of `OuterA`.

> Why is InnerA object reference not required to be passed to SubclassC constructor?

Because when creating a `SubclassC`, under the hood, an instance of its superclass will be created first, i.e there will be a instance of `InnerA`. You can actually look on `SubclassC` as a *special* kind of `InnerA`.

Comment: But why doesn't the language allow you to have a constructor of `SubclassC` with no-arguments that you could use by writing `new OuterA().new SubclassC()` just like it allows you to write `new OuterA().new InnerA()`? What am I missing?

Comment: It's required because of the definition of `InnerA`. `InnerA` (and all its subclasses) will **always** need an `OuterA` to be instantiated. Otherwise, (if you don't have to provide an `OuterA` instance) you would break the link between `OuterA` and `InnerA` (i.e. you would ignore the fact that `InnerA` is nested in `OuterA`). If `InnerA` was `static`, it would **not** be required

Comment: But I did provide an `OuterA` instance.

Comment: @pbabcdefp, `new OuterA().new SubclassC()` is not allowed simply because `SubclassC` is not nested within `OuterA`.

Comment: @kocko I know polymorphically speaking, SubclassC is an instance of InnerA. So we have two different instances each of InnerA and SubclassC. But there is only 1 object that we have created which belongs to SubclassC. Where have we created a distinct object of InnerA (other than SubclassC object which InnerA instance refers to)?

Comment: We haven't. When you create `SubclassC` you don't have instance of `InnerA`, even though `InnerA`'s constructor is called before the one for `SubclassC`. What happens is that you have **one** instance (which is an instance of `SubclassC`) and this instance is **compatible** with `InnerA` (i.e. can be casted). `InnerA`'s constructor is needed to be called, because it's part of `SubclassC`'s definition.

Answer (score 4):

> 1. Why do I need to pass OuterA object reference to SubclassC constructor for the .java file to compile?

Because `InnerA` is an inner class of `OuterA`. This means that an object of type `OuterA.InnerA` or any of its subtypes, such as `SubclassC`, can only exist in the context of an enclosing class (`OuterA` in this case) instance.

This is called a **Qualified superclass constructor invocation**. From the [JLS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.8.7.1):

> Qualified superclass constructor invocations begin with a Primary expression . They allow a subclass constructor to explicitly specify the newly created object's immediately enclosing instance with respect to the direct superclass (§8.1.3). **This may be necessary when the superclass is an inner class**.

If you don't need to link the `SubclassC` instance to an already existing instance of `OuterA`, you can create the new `OuterA` object in the `SuperclassC` constructor:

```
static class SubclassC extends OuterA.InnerA {
    SubclassC() {
        new OuterA().super();
    }
}
```

> 2. Why is InnerA object reference not required to be passed to SubclassC constructor?

Since `SubclassC` extends `OuterA.InnerA`, **when you do `outerRef.super()` you are calling the `OuterA.InnerA` constructor**. To see that this is the case, consider the code below:

```
public class Example {
    static class OuterA {
        OuterA() {
            System.out.println("Call OuterA constructor");
        }
        class InnerA {
            InnerA() {
                System.out.println("Call InnerA constructor");
            }

        }
    }

    static class SubclassC extends OuterA.InnerA {
        SubclassC(OuterA outerRef) {
            outerRef.super();
            System.out.println("Call SuperclassC constructor");
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        OuterA outerA = new OuterA();
        System.out.println("Before new SuperclassC()");
        new SubclassC(outerA);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Call OuterA constructor
Before new SuperclassC()
Call InnerA constructor
Call SuperclassC constructor
```

Comment: Great that you pointed out that's actually calling InnerA ctor!

Answer (score 2):

```
1.Why do I need to pass OuterA object reference to SubclassC constructor for the .java file to compile?
```

Because you need to know the name of the instance of the class in order to call the function because `SubclassC` extends the class `OuterA.InnerA`: `SubclassC extends OuterA.InnerA {`

```
SubclassC(OuterA outerRef) {
        outerRef.super();
```

2nd

```
2. Why is InnerA object reference not required to be passed to SubclassC constructor?
```

Because Innera is inside Outtera which you are calling when you are creating the object       `new SubclassC(new OuterA());` (i.e. you don't need the creation of separate object since `InnerA` is inside `OuterA`. Creating the `OuterA` is enough in this case

Comment: "Because you need to know the name of the object" - objects don't have names.

Comment: true. changed it to the name of the instance of the class

Comment: No. Instances _are_ objects and neither have names. You don't "need to know the name" of the object, you need to have a reference to the object.

Answer (score 2):

We expect two things to happen before a constructor is run:

- the base class (`Object` if `extends` is not used) constructor should have been run
- the enclosing instance, if any, should have been fully constructed and a reference to it is going around in the program

Java enforces the first rule by automatically placing a `super()` call at the beginning of your constructors. Note there isn't anything as a *parent instance*: when you do `new File()` you don't need to provide an `Object` - so no mistery you don't need `InnerA` when building `SubclassC`.

When a non-static class is defined in the lexical scope of another class it can access fields of the enclosing object:

```
class Outer {
  int val;
  class Inner {
    int val() {
      return val; // <-- we can access val, it's in scope
    }
  }
}
```

so it's clear that we need a link to it. Here is how the link is usually created:

```
Outer outer = new Outer();
Outer.Inner inner = outer.new Inner(); // baroque, I admit
```

The very same thing happens in the first line of a class extending `Inner`:

```
class InnerExtended extends Outer.Inner {
  public InnerExtended(Outer outer) {
    outer.super(); // <-- calls Outer.Inner ctor
  }
}
```

Even if it's not easy to see the similarities:

```
super();            // plain superclass ctor call
outer.new Inner();  // instantiation of inner class
outer.super();      // super() call in class extending inner
```

Comment: I've just worked out the reason for the apparent inconsistency. If `InnerExtended` was also nested within `Outer`, then every instance of `InnerExtended` would actually need *two* instances of `Outer` (the enclosng instance of `Inner` and the enclosing instance of `InnerExtended`). These can be different! Writing `outer1.new InnerExtended(outer2)` would then make `outer1` the enclosing instance of the `InnerExtended` and `outer2` the enclosing instance of its parent. When `InnerExtended` is not also nested within `Outer`, there is only one `Outer` required, but the syntax must be consistent.